# Using HTML alongside Jade within the express framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am adding a blog section to my site, which is built on `node.js`, with the `express` framework. In order to make things easier for myself in terms of styling, etc, I'm trying to use the bootsrap example blog shown [at this link](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/#) and [at this github](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-clean-blog) alongside all of my views. I placed the page in the root of the project, and set my controller as follows:

```
exports.blog = function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('/blog.html', { root: 'blog' });
}
```

This points to the `blog` folder, inside of which is `blog.html`.

Unfortunately, I'm running into issues with loading the `scripts` and `links`. For example, the following `link` would, I think, reference the `clean-blog.min.css` file, kept inside of the css folder, which is inside of the blog folder, which is inside the root directory. However, when I open my console, it shows me that these haven't loaded.

```
<link href="blog/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You're not using Jade at all. You're sending a static HTML file, `blog.html` down. Re the links, express serves static files from your app's `public` directory, so you need to make sure any linked assets are in there and the paths match; i.e. your css file would be at `public/blog/css/clean-blog.min.css`

Comment: The rest of the app uses jade...it's built on https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter. I'm trying to avoid placing all of those files into the public directory, since they will be served up to the rest of the views.

Comment: OK, was just an observation from your posted code :) So is your CSS etc in the `public` dir?

Comment: yes, for the rest of the code it is in the public directory